# Comparar arrays en python

Tags: mysql, python, programación-funcional

Tengo un problema cuando quiero comparar dos resultados obtenidos de dos consultas sql distintas; ejemplo `queryUno[0]` y `queryDos[0]`.

Resulta que he intentado utilizar `list(set(list1).difference(list2))` y no me dio resultado ya que me imprimió en pantalla esto :

```
queryUno[0]:
`['A', 'Y', 'C', 'B', 'L']` 

queryDos[0]
['Y', 'C', 'U', 'L']
```

Y necesito que me imprima los resultados (ejemplo):

```
queryUno[0]:
Manzana
Peras
Bananas

queryDos[0]:
Manzana
Peras
```

```python
list(set(queryUno[0]) - set(queryDos[0])) O list(set(queryUno[0]).difference(queryDos[0]))
```

Como resultado debería entregarme `Bananas` . Quiero utilizar una funcion en python que me de el mismo resultado que `array_diff` en PHP.

Agregado:

Gracias a todos por las respuestas. 
Estoy utilizando Mysql con Python.

```
  comprobante = Mysql.cursor()
    comprobante_s.execute(comprobante)
    comprobante_sys = comprobante_s.fetchall()
    for items in comprobante_sys:
        items[0]
   list(set(items[0]) - set(queryDos[0]))
```

He convertido en un conjunto set() y dato que me entrega es :

```
['Y', 'C', 'U', 'L']
```

Y necesito que me entregue los datos enteros, citando al ejemplo anterior:

```
queryUno[0]:
Manzana
Peras
Bananas

queryDos[0]:
Manzana
Peras
list(set(items[0]) - set(queryDos[0]))
```

Resultado `Bananas`

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta. Tal como lo haces equivale al `array_diff` de PHP, por lo que si no te funciona tiene que ser motivado por otra cosa. Mejora la pregunta completando el código para que podamos reproducir el error y especifica mejor cómo estás aplicándolo a los ejemplos que pones.

Comment: Como te comento en mi respuesta habría que ver para empezar que te retorna `queryUno[0]` porque das a entender que retorna una lista de Python pero parece que lo que hace es imprimir, el error debe estar por ahí pero nos falta esa información.

Comment: A ver si me voy enterando, ¿lo que pretendes es comparar dos bases de datos o dos tablas de una misma base cogiendo el primer elemento de cada fila?, es decir creas una lista con el primer elemento de cada fila de la base de datos uno, creas otra lista con los primeros elementos por fila de la base de datos 2 y luego comparas ambas listas. Si es eso dilo y modifico la respuesta porque el problema está aquí, el método `difference()` es correcto.

Comment: Si lo que quieres es lo que explico en el mensaje anterior deberias hacer algo asi para obtener cada lista: `queryUno = [row[0] for row in comprobante_s.fetchall()]` o directamente creas el conjunto: `queryUno = set(row[0] for row in comprobante_s)`

Comment: @FJSevilla es eso lo que quiero hacer, voy a intentar obtener el resultado aplicando lo que me indicas  - queryUno = set(row[0] for row in comprobante_s) -

Comment: @FJSevilla el problema que estoy teniendo al usar difference() que me esta dando como resultado letras ['Y', 'C', 'U', 'L'] y no cadenas de texto, que serian los datos extraídos de la base de datos.

Comment: Voy a actualizar la respuesta poniendo un ejemplo usando sqlite3 incluido en el estandar de Python porque ahora no tengo a mano MySQL (de todas formas los métodos son identicos). Miralo a ver que te parece y si tus datos son parecidos a los ejemplos que pongo.

Answer (score 3):

Si lo que quieres es que te retorne los elementos que estan en **alguna de las listas pero no en la otra** puedes usar el método [`symmetric_difference()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) o `^`.

```
a = ['Manzana','Peras','Bananas']
b = ['Manzana','Peras']
print(set(a).symmetric_difference(set(b)))
```

Nos retorna:

```
{'Bananas'}
```

Otro ejemplo:

```
a = ['A', 'Y', 'C', 'B', 'L']` 
b = ['Y', 'C', 'U', 'L']
print(set(a) ^ set(b))
```

Nos retorna:

```
{'B', 'U', 'A'}
```

Si usas el método `difference()` o `-` te retorna solo los **elementos que están en la primera lista pero no en la segunda**:

```
a = ['A', 'Y', 'C', 'B', 'L']` 
b = ['Y', 'C', 'U', 'L']
print(set(a) - set(b))
```

Nos retorna:

```
{'B', 'A'}
```

Como ves ambos deben ser [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)

Faltan algunos datos como que base de datos usas, como almacenas y extraes esos datos desde la base de datos, etc... Para que funcionen estos métodos tienes que poder transformar los datos en un conjunto (`set()`).

Por otro lado `list(set(queryUno[0]) - set(queryDos[0]))` crea un objeto (una lista) que contiene la diferencia entre los dos conjuntos pero no te va a imprimir nada, necesitarias hacer algo como:

`print(list(set(queryUno[0]) - set(queryDos[0])))`

**Actualización incluyendo ejemplo usando [`sqlite3`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sqlite3.html):**

Voy a crear una base de datos localmente (llamada `datos.db`) con dos tablas llamadas `stock1` y `stock2`. Cada tabla tiene 3 columnas que son `fruta`, `kilogramos` y `cajas`. El objetivo es comparar las dos tablas usando la columna `frutas` e imprimir aquellas frutas que esten en `stocks1` y no en `stocks2`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sqlite3



#Creamos una base de datos llamada datos.db
con = sqlite3.connect('datos.db')

cursor = con.cursor()

#Creamos una tabla llamada stock1 y añadimos 3 filas
cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE stocks1 (fruta, kilogramos, cajas)''')
items = [('Manzanas','12','4'), ('Peras','10','2'),('Bananas','5','1')]
cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO stocks1 VALUES (?,?,?)', items)

#Creamos una tabla llamada stock1 y añadimos 2 filas
cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE stocks2 (fruta, kilogramos, cajas)''')
items = [('Manzanas','12','4'), ('Peras','10','2')]
cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO stocks2 VALUES (?,?,?)', items)

con.commit()
con.close()


#Accedemos a nuestra base de datos 
con = sqlite3.connect('datos.db');
cursor = con.cursor()

#Extraemos el primer elemento de cada fila de la tabla stocks1
##y lo almacenamos en la lista queryUno
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM stocks1")
queryUno = set(row[0] for row in cursor)

#Extraemos el primer elemento de cada fila de la tabla stocks2
##y lo almacenamos en la lista queryDos
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM stocks2")
queryDos = set(row[0] for row in cursor)

#Comparamos las dos tablas
print(queryUno - queryDos)

con.close()
```

Esto nos imprime:

```
>>> ['Bananas']
```

Saludos.

Comment: Entiendo he convertido los datos en conjunto set() pero obtengo solo letras y datos completos ['Y', 'C', 'U', 'L']. Actualice la pregunta...

Answer (score 2):

Lo que se debe hacer es declarar las dos listas:

`queryUno=['Manzana', 'Peras', 'Bananas']` y `queryDos=['Manzana', 'Peras']`

y luego crear secuencias de cada uno, substraer `queryDos` de `queryUno`, y crear una lista:

`list(set(queryUno) - set(queryDos))`

Esepero sea lo que estás buscando.

Comment: Entiendo he convertido los datos en conjunto set() pero obtengo solo letras y datos completos ['Y', 'C', 'U', 'L']. Actualice la pregunta...

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a todos y a @FJSevilla, definitivamente estaba indicando mal la posición del dato que me extraía de la base de datos.

```
queryUno = set(row[0] for row in comprobante_s)
```

Coloque la posición `row[13]` que ocupa el dato en cada tabla y funciono perfecto.
Luego utilice `list(set(queryUno[0]).difference(queryDos[0]))` y obtuve el resultado propuesto.
Gracias a todos por las respuestas..